# Details of moving Ubuntu 16.04 to a new partition on new drive

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a working installation of Ubuntu 16.04.  I just installed a new SSD and would like to move the Ubuntu installation to a partition on the new drive.

I'm following the instructions at 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition
but I've run into a deviation from the expectations outlined in the instructions.

When I get to the step that sets a new UUID for the newly cloned partition
`tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1`
the duplicated UUID doesn't change.

I'm also concerned that my original installation has a small FAT32 partition at the beginning, prior to the main partition, but these instructions don't ask me to create that first.

In the end, I want to install Windows in a second partition on this same drive and make the machine dual-boot.

I guess I have two questions:
Is there a better way to do this than is explained by the instructions I'm using?
If not, what do I need to do to get the UUID to change successfully?

Comment: *" a small FAT32 partition at the beginning"* - That would be your EFI partition

Comment: If this is an UEFI partition with gpt partitioning, you should not copy partitions. You can copy entire drives. The gpt partition system has GUID for each partition and partition table and backup partition table must match GUID. They may be a long work around with gdisk or sgdisk. Better to just reinstall & copy /home and perhaps some settings from /etc. And export list of installed apps and reinstall those. Good time to test that backups work.

Comment: @oldfred - For various reasons that I don't want to go into for fear of derailing the conversation, it will be better for me if I can figure out how to move the entire partition, or as you suggested, maybe work out how to clone the contents of the old, smaller SSD onto the new, larger one.   I'm wondering, based on what you've said, if it might be better to disconnect the old SSD, connect the new one, install Windows (Ugh. 
 I apologize for having to use that word), then work out how to get the old partition over to the new SSD having let Windows get itself all comfy and in place?

Comment: If old drive is smaller, you should be able to clone entire drive. Then reformat or change UUIDs/GUIDs on old drive so you do not have duplicates, which are not allowed. You may have to reinstall boot loaders or make other repairs.

Comment: ...which is at the heart of my original post.  Why doesn't <code>sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1</code> change the UUID of /dev/sdb1?  It may be a moot point though.  If I'm cloning the entire drive, then I no longer need the old drive at all.  I would just remove it from the machine.